# Specialized friend function in C++

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization, partial-specialization

I have a function template `foo` that has to perform different computations depending on whether the template parameter is a real or a complex number. In any case, the result will be a real number, e.g. `double`, even if the template parameter is `std::complex<double>`. Therefore, my function looks as follows:

```
template <class S>
struct RealType
{
  typedef S type;
};

template <class S>
struct RealType<std::complex<S> >
{
  typedef S type;
};

template <class S>
class C;

template <class S>
typename RealType<S>::type foo(C<S> &c);

template <class S>
typename RealType<std::complex<S> >::type foo(C<std::complex<S> > &c);
```

Now `foo` must be a friend function of the class `C`, so I made the following declaration:

```
template <class S>
class C
{
  friend typename RealType<S>::type foo(C<S> &c);
  // ...
};
```

However, when I instantiate `C<std::complex<double> >` the compiler says that `foo` cannot access the private members of `c`. It works fine for `C<double>`. Is there any solution to this (that works with C++98)? I understand that `foo` cannot be a member of `C`, as this will prevent the partial specialization.

BTW: Is this really a specialization? The signatures of both versions of `foo` look the same, but in fact they are somewhat different when the real types are plugged in.

Comment: IIRC you need some thing like: `template<class U> friend typename RealType<U>::type foo(C<U> &c);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that `class C` declares `foo` a friend *after* `foo` has been declared.

You may need to use forward declarations for that:

```
template <class S> class C;

// foo declarations here

template <class S> class C 
{ 
    template<class X> friend typename RealType<X>::type foo(C<X> &c); // friend the template
    friend typename RealType<S>::type foo<>(C &c); // friend the specialization
};
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is the case in my code, just like in the example above.

Comment: You are right, your code actually solves the problem. I was too focused on the forward declaration, so I didn't see that you declare the friend functions differently. Also, my real code has some more template parameters, but now it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: Note: As shown in the referenced code, the line with `template <class X>` seems to be unnecessary. I think I will have to check again what `<>` does exactly.

Comment: @cthl I mentioned in the comment what these two different syntaxes do.